# How do I find occurence of element inside of first element xpath

Tags: php, xpath

With a XML-structure like this:

```
<w:document>
    <w:body>
      <w:p>{textcontent}</w:p>
      <w:p>
          <w:drawing>
          </w:drawing>
      </w:p>
      <w:p>{no textcontent}</w:p>
      <w:p>
          <w:drawing>
          </w:drawing>
      </w:p>
      <w:p>{no textcontent}</w:p>
      <w:p>text..</w:p>

      <w:tbl>three</w:tbl>
      <w:p>four</w:p>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

**I want to check occurrence of  and count nr of drawings**

**I've tried this:**

```
$document = new DOMDocument(); 
$document->loadXML($xml_str);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace(
   'wspace', 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'
);

$pindex = 0;
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//wspace:p') as $index => $p_node) 
{
    if (strlen($p_node->textContent)>0) {

        //I just want to know if drawing exists in this $p_node..
        //if the the node contains any content
        $child_nodes = $xpath->evaluate('//wspace:drawing', $p_node);
        var_dump($child_nodes[0]);
        $pindex++;
        //But I get an object for each pnode. I just want an object when there
        //is an actualy <w:drawing> inside of <p> (item with index 1,3 in above example)
    }
}
```

How do I check nr of occurences for the `<w:p><w:drawing>` ?

I could do like this to count the occurences:

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//wspace:p//wspace:drawing') as $index => $node) 
{
    var_dump($node);
}
```

but I need the index of the p (`$pindex`) as well.

I've also been trying with `evaluate('/child')`, `evaluate('node()/child')` without success.

What is going wrong with my expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly from the xpath angle:

Adding

```
<root  xmlns:w='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'>
[your xml above]
</root>
```

before and after your xml and trying

```
count(//w:p/w:drawing)
```

gave the output:

> 2.0

If you need an integer instead of float, change the expression to

```
round(count(//w:p/w:drawing))
```

Hope that helps with the rest.

Comment: I don't just want to count the occurences. I want the fetch related index of <w:p> as well.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found an answer to my own question:-)

**Instead of:**

```
$child_nodes = $xpath->evaluate('//wspace:drawing', $p_node);
```

**I simply use childNodes on the current $p_node:**

```
$child_nodes = $p_node->childNodes;
foreach($child_nodes as $rc) 
{
    if ($rc->localName == 'drawing') 
    {
     $img_count++;
     echo 'P=' . $pindex;
    }
}
```